# LWJGL glVertexAttributePointer Error: Cannot use offsets when Array Buffer Object is disabled

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

In my program is throwing the error: `org.lwjgl.opengl.OpenGLException: Cannot use offsets when Array Buffer Object is disabled`

I know that this can happen if you don't call glPointer()/glBindBuffer() in the right order
So here is what I am doing, roughly:

```
GL20.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferID);
GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(attributeIndex); //In this case, 0
GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(attributeIndex, attributeLength, GL_FLOAT, isNormalized, stride, offset);
...
```

Obviously, I allocate the buffer before this code, and have checked that bufferID is nonzero and not -1

However, when doing `glVertexAttributePointer()` I get the error: Cannot use offsets when Array Buffer Object is disabled

Did I forget to call something?

Comment: Can you be moe specific of what the problem is?

Comment: Awesome you know how to use `glVertexAttributePointer()`, but what is your actual problem?

Comment: I get org.lwjgl.opengl.OpenGLException: Cannot use offsets when Array Buffer Object is disabled

Comment: http://lwjgl.org/forum/index.php?topic=4494.0

Comment: In that thread, the OP was calling glPoint before Bind, which was the problem

Comment: Is `bufferID` non-zero? This sounds like an extremely obtuse way for lwjgl to say **do not use client memory**.

Comment: Yes, bufferID is nonzero

Comment: It could also be a cryptic way of saying you have no VAO bound when you tried to make these calls. In a core profile context, they are invalid operations unless you have a VAO bound. But why lwjgl would phrase the error message that way, I could not say.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I used VAOs, it didn't change anything

Comment: I solved the problem, I was getting a invalid enum error in glBindBuffer because there was a bug in a switch statement of mine that made it return GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, instead of GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, and when I changed that, it fixed the problem